# Canonical section of a Hirzebruch surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

What is the definition of the canonical section of the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(-2)\oplus \mathcal{O})$?

Comment: I think people use this terminology to mean the unique section with selfintersection $-2$. (This corresponds to one of the line bundle summands, but I don't want to say which one without knowing your conventions about projectivisation of a vector bundle!)

Comment: Hm, I am not sure which conventions are you referring to?

Comment: Some people say $\mathbf P(E)$ is the space of lines in $E$, others say it is the space of hyperplanes in $E$. Depending on which convention you use, the negative section will correspond to one or the other line bundle summand.

Comment: I am thinking of $\mathbb{P}(E)$ as lines in $E,$ so that should then correspond to section of $\mathcal{O}(-2)$ I guess?

Comment: Go read Hartshorne Proposition V.2.8. As Asal mentioned above, be aware that the conventions may differ from wherever you're reading this from.